# Runtime compilation of kotlin code throws RuntimeException (WARN: Failed to initialize native filesystem for Windows)

Tags: windows, kotlin, compilation, filesystems, jsr223

I am using the [KotlinJsr223](http://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-script-util/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineFactoryExamples.kt) from the kotlin std-lib, to compile kotlin code at runtime.

Basically to generalize the problem, I have the following code:

```kotlin
val engine = KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory().scriptEngine as KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine
val kotlinScript = engine.compile("""println("Hello World")""") as KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.CompiledKotlinScript
```

As soon as the second line runs (that compiles the code), a Warning followed by RuntimException is thrown.

The exception main lines are:

```java
WARN: Failed to initialize native filesystem for Windows
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory.
```

> Looks like there's some problem in creating filesystem.

[Full stack trace's gist is here](https://gist.github.com/Animeshz/dc57e9e44e061abd108a01e9bbc1e9f6), if you'd like to check.

Is there way to solve the problem?

The compilation does not exit the application, its sort of like warning. After that its like delay of 5 second and then compilation succeed but still 5 second break and console warning must be some kind of threat, that is needed to be fixed.

---

### My Runtime Environment are as following:

- Windows 10 build 1909
- Java - 11.0.4
- Kotlin - 1.3.72
- JVM - Target 1.8

Comment: Did you find an answer, having same problem with exact same Kotlin version.

Comment: @YazanJaber Nope, I've just started a bounty for finding the answer, you could upvote for making this question more active to the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue only occurs when running in IDE and can be mitigated with `org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.environment.setIdeaIoUseFallback`.

This can be seen in the example [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/61def4cdc5c2ac3e754a9eb11c1aa1ecc075871c/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/test/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineIT.kt#L30-L32).

Comment: Thanks alot! One thing to notice is that the compilation still takes about 5-10 seconds, is this because of the compilation is slow or something else?